# Loading images async in WPF with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, async-await

I'm making an app that loads several images from a local directory or list of file names. I'm new to WPF, MVVM, and have never really been that great at concurrency stuff. So my question is what am I missing in my code to make images load asynchronously?

```
public class ThumbnailGridViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<Picture> Pictures
    {
        get
        {
            if (_filterOn)
            {
                return new ObservableCollection<Picture>(
                    _pictures.Where(pic => pic.ImageName.Contains(_searchFilter)).ToList());
            }
            else
            {
                return _pictures;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            _pictures = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ThumbnailGridViewModel(IDialogService modalDialog)
    {
        //...

        Messenger.Default.Register<ObservableCollection<Picture>>(this, OnPicturesLoaded);
        //...
    }

    private void OnPicturesLoaded(ObservableCollection<Picture> pictures)
    {
        Pictures = pictures;
    }
}

public class VepixWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private async void OnOpenFolder(SearchOption option)
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog folderDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            if (folderDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                List<Picture> pictures = await (_pictureRepo.GetPicturesFromFolderAsync(folderDialog.SelectedPath, option));
                Messenger.Default.Send(new ObservableCollection<Picture>(pictures));
            }
        }

    private async void OnOpenFiles()
    {
        OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog()
        {
            Multiselect = true,
            Filter = "Image Files|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.gif"
        };
        if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            List<Picture> pictures = await (_pictureRepo.GetPicturesAsync(fileDialog.FileNames));
            Messenger.Default.Send(new ObservableCollection<Picture>(pictures));
        }
    }
}

public class PictureRepository : IPictureRepository
{
    public PictureRepository()
    {
        _fileService = new FileService();
    }

    public async Task<List<Picture>> GetPicturesAsync(string[] files)
    {
        var fileBytes = await _fileService.ReadBytesFromFilesAsync(files.ToList());
        return await LoadPicturesAsync(fileBytes);
    }

    public async Task<List<Picture>> GetPicturesFromFolderAsync(string folderPath, SearchOption option)
    {
        var fileBytes = await _fileService.GetFilesAndBytesFromDirectoryAsync(folderPath, _supportedImagesFilterList, option);
        return await LoadPicturesAsync(fileBytes);
    }

    private Task<List<Picture>> LoadPicturesAsync(Dictionary<string, byte[]> fileBytes)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew<List<Picture>>(() =>
        {
            List<Picture> pictures = new List<Picture>();
            Parallel.ForEach(fileBytes, file =>
            {
                 pictures.Add(new Picture(BitmapService.ConvertByteArrayToBitmapImage(file.Value), file.Key));
            });
            return pictures;
        });
    }
}

public class FileService : IFileService
{
    public async Task<Dictionary<string, byte[]>> GetFilesAndBytesFromDirectoryAsync(string path, List<string> searchPattern, SearchOption option)
    {
        var files = new List<string>();
        if (Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                searchPattern.ForEach( sp =>
                    files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(path, sp, option))));
        }

        return await ReadBytesFromFilesAsync(files);
    }

    public byte[] ReadBytesFromFile(string file)
        => File.ReadAllBytes(file);

    public async Task<Dictionary<string, byte[]>> ReadBytesFromFilesAsync(List<string> files)
    {
        //todo: i think i will change this return type to just List<byte[]>
        var bytes = new Dictionary<string, byte[]>();
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            files.ForEach(file => bytes.Add(file, ReadBytesFromFile(file))));

        return bytes;
    }
}

public static class BitmapService
{
    public static BitmapImage ConvertByteArrayToBitmapImage(Byte[] bytes)
    {
        var image = new BitmapImage();
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
            {
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                image.BeginInit();
                image.StreamSource = stream;
                image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                image.EndInit();
                image.Freeze();
            }

        return image;
    }
}
```

Comment: Without going through all that code, in the `ConvertByteArrayToBitmapImage` method you should set `image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad` before calling `EndInit` and dispose of the MemoryStream (ideally by putting it in a `using` block).

Comment: @Clemens, thanks for the input. I have made the change.

Comment: You may also call `image.Freeze()` to make it cross-thread accessible. Then you may call `ConvertByteArrayToBitmapImage` outside `Dispatcher.Invoke`.

Comment: @Clemens, thanks again. I don't think I need to Dispatcher.Invoke() anymore, so I got rid of that.

Comment: I am getting closer to make this asynchronous now. It seems like the UI is now only freezing when the collection is added to my Pictures Property. I need to look more into that.